# Get handled error in $.ajax Fail function

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Following is my code for ajax call. I have a Asp.net MVC as a backend application.

```
   $.ajax({
            url: someUrl,
            method: 'get',
            dataType : 'html'
        }).success(function (result) {
            $("#mainDiv").html(result);
            ajaxindicatorstop();
        })
        .fail(function (data, status, error) {                
            handleFailedAjax();
            ajaxindicatorstop();
        });
```

When my application throws any error, it still executes the success callback instead of fail.
My guess is, as I have handled all the errors at server side using Application_Error in global.asax, jquery doesn't see any error and goes to success giving me the status 200 (OK). Is there any way where I can still get the error status code and get the fail part of ajax call executed.

In my application I have mixed type of ajax calls which expect json or html as a result.

The error handler always returns html (Generic error message). Due to this my ajax call with dataType 'json' fails and goes to error/fail callback (nothing about the actual error).

Comment: You shouldn't be returning 200 from the server if the call failed for whatever reason. Status code 200 represents a success. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Its the handling of error on server side making that status 200.

Comment: If you've "handled" the error then presumably you're returning the desired result in that case. If you've not then I don't think you'll want to be returning status 200 at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
$(document).ajaxError(
    function (e, request) {
        if(request.status !== 200){
            // code here..
        }
    }   
);
```

Comment: There are already $.ajax.fail written, If I setup ajaxError it will affect all other ajax calls

Comment: one solution is that change ajaxError before and after your code